# Relation between two summation

Tags: summation

I have two summation formulae
\begin{align*}
s(n)=\sum_{p=0}^{n}\binom{n}{p}\frac{(\sqrt{2})^p k^{n-p}}{\mathrm{i}^{p}}
\end{align*}
and 
\begin{align*}
s(n+2)=\sum_{p=0}^{n+2}\binom{n+2}{p}\frac{(\sqrt{2})^p k^{n+2-p}}{\mathrm{i}^{p}}
\end{align*}
where $\mathrm{i}$ is unit imaginary number. How can we write $s(n+2)$ in terms of $ s(n)$?

Comment: Is there anything special about the i that looks different?

Comment: Welcome to [MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com). It is mandatory on this site to add your own attempts and where you face problems, then others can help you.

Comment: $s(n+2)=s(n)+\text{thing inside the sum}(n+2)+\text{thing inside the sum}(n+1)$

Comment: Thats right.....I am looking for something multiple?